# Opening and closing orders on same candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to learn Pine Script so I can start backtesting my ideas. This is my first attempt at backtesting a strategy, so I'm keeping it simple. I'm trying to make a mean reversion strategy based on higher time-frame candles. If a candle is bearish (close is lower than high), I want to open a long position when the next candle opens. The opposite for a short position. At the close of each candle, the open position is closed (either in profit or loss, doesn't matter.) So an order should be placed when the candle opens, and then the order is closed when the candle closes.

My understanding is the script executes on each candle open. First, I have the script set to close the open position. Then I have an if/else function to check if the current open (basically the same as the previous close) is lower or higher than the previous candle's open. Then it opens a long or short position accordingly.

The strategy runs in the tester, but the trades don't show up on the chart, so I can't tell if it's executing the logic correctly. Here's the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay = true, shorttitle = "My Strat")

strategy.close_all()

if open < open[1]
    strategy.entry("Long entry", strategy.long)
else
    strategy.entry("Short entry", strategy.short)
```

Comment: On what ticker and timeframe are you running this?

Comment: Also, is your problem not having any orders at all or opening and closing orders on the same candle?

Comment: I'm trying to run it on a EUR/USD daily chart. My problem right now is that the trades aren't showing on the chart, so I can't verify if it's executing them according to the logic that I want. The performance summary is showing that it's executing trades.

Answer (score 0):

first off, the order will be placed on the bar after the calculation, for historical reasons.
On live bars this will do what you said, as long you have
*Settings --> Properties --> Recalculate --> On every tick* set to active.

There are several ways to test your `if` condition...

---

Use a variable to store the condition state in it, and then use `plotchar()` to show you what is going on.

```
longCondition = open > open[1]
plotchar(longCondition, "Long", "L", location.abovebar, color.teal)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = open < open[1]
plotchar(shortCondition, "Short", "S", location.belowbar, color.red)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

---

You can use the `log.*()` functions inside a local scope to get a message when something is executed.

```
if open > open[1]
    log.info("Long")
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

if open < open[1]
    log.info("Short")
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

---

Use the alert message to show when something has triggered.

```
if open > open[1]
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, alert_message = "Long")

if open < open[1]
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, alert_message = "Short")
```

This approach will only work on live bars.

---

**Additional explanation ...**

There wont be a order on every candle because this way the orders have to cancel the opposing order out first.

To get both orders out at the same time you have to set them apart and preferably use limit orders instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make it open a trade and close on the same bar on the historical bars. It will either open it at the next bar's open or when the current bar closes. You can change this behavior via the *Properties* tab by checking *On bar close* option.

On EURUSD / Daily chart, there will be MANY trades  (more than 9000) so that it will throw an error. You can see the error message if you click on the red exclamation mark next to your indicator. However, it will log the entries to the List of trades.

BTCBUSD is on the weekly or monthly timeframe a good pair because there are not too many historical bars available.

[image]